# Ember.js Select component - issue detecting when value is selected

Tags: javascript, ember.js

We have a dashboard with two tabs that represent two distinct groups of which the authenticated user is a member.  Each of these tabs has a Select component representing options for a group-specific field called 'foo'.  The Select component has its value set to foo.  We have a method which observes foo and saves the group when foo changes.

I only want this method to be called when the user changes the value of the Select component.  However, it is also called when the group is switched, since the new group has a different value for foo, which initializes the select component.

**How can I ignore the value changed events that result from the select object's initialization?**